# Equation of a LINE SEGMENT

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

The equation of an ellipse in the complex plane is given by

$$
|z - f_1| + |z - f_2| = k
$$

where $z$ is an arbitrary complex number, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the foci, and $k$ is some constant such that $k \ge 2a$, $a$ being the length of the semi-major axis. This got me into thinking about what happens when $0 < k < 2a$.

While I haven't found an answer to that (though, I'd love to know), it struck me that if $k = |f_2 - f_1|$, it is supposed to represent the line segment joining $f_1$ and $f_2$.

**My reasoning:** $z$, $f_1$ and $f_2$ can be thought to form a triangle if $|z - f_1| + |z - f_2| > |f_2 - f_1|$. Now if the inequality is replaced by an equality, then $z$ must lie on the line joining $f_1$ and $f_2$. It must also be in between $f_1$ and $f_2$ because the equality won't hold otherwise.

Is this argument correct? And if it is, can I actually represent a line segment joining any two points $a$ and $b$ by this equation?

$$
|z - a| + |z - b| = |a - b|.
$$

Also, can this equation be reduced to a form that can be handled algebraically?

Comment: That's correct, the locus of $z$ given by $|z - a| + |z - b| = |a - b|$ is the line segment between $a$ and $b$ (including the endpoints). `can this equation be reduced to a form that can be handled algebraically?` You can replace the magnitudes with $|w|=\sqrt{w \bar w}\,$, though it's not clear what kind of algebraic form you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppose $b=0$ (otherwise, do a translation) and $a\ne0$. The equation is
$$
|z|+|z-a|=|a|
$$
Write $a=ru$, where $|u|=1$ and $r=|a|$, and $z=wu$. Then the equation is
$$
|w|+|w-r|=r
$$
Squaring gives
$$
w\bar{w}+(w-r)(\bar{w}-r)+2|w|\,|w-r|=r^2
$$
and, simplifying,
$$
2|w|\,|w-r|=r(w+\bar{w})-2w\bar{w}\tag{*}
$$
If we set $w=x+yi$, this requires $rx-(x^2+y^2)\ge0$. Under this condition, we can square (*):
$$
4w\bar{w}(w-r)(\bar{w}-r)=
r^2(w^2+2w\bar{w}+\bar{w}^2)+4w^2\bar{w}^2-4rw\bar{w}(w+\bar{w})
$$
or, simplifying,
$$
r^2(w-\bar{w})^2=0
$$
Therefore $w=\bar{w}$ is real and so $y=0$. The condition $rx-(x^2+y^2)\ge0$ now becomes $0\le x\le r$.

Thus $z=xu$, where $0\le x\le |a|$, so $z$ is a point on the segment connecting $0$ to $a$. Conversely, any such point satisfies the initial equation.